# Method overload resolution with regards to generics and IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, overloading, overload-resolution

I noticed this the other day, say you have two overloaded methods:

```
public void Print<T>(IEnumerable<T> items) {
    Console.WriteLine("IEnumerable T"); 
}
public void Print<T>(T item) {
    Console.WriteLine("Single T"); 
}
```

This code:

```
public void TestMethod() {  
    var persons = new[] { 
        new Person { Name = "Yan", Age = 28 },
        new Person { Name = "Yinan", Age = 28 } 
    };  
    Print(persons);
    Print(persons.ToList()); 
}
```

prints:

```
Single T
Single T
```

Why are `Person[]` and `List<Person>` better matched to `T` than they are to `IEnumerable<T>` in these cases?

Thanks,

**UPDATE:**
Also, if you have another overload

```
public void Print<T>(List<T> items) {
    Console.WriteLine("List T");
}
```

`Print(persons.ToList());` will actually print `List T` instead of `Single T`.

Comment: Calling `Print(persons as IEnumerable<Person>);` should call the other method.  The generic method lookup doesn't do an implicit cast from `Person[]` to `IEnumerable<Person>`. When you call `person.ToList()` your immediate type is a `List<Person>` (also requiring no implicit cast).

Comment: +1 I've been fiddling with this issue for a bit.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The first part of your question (without the List-specific overload) is easy. Let's consider the Array call, because it works the same for both calls:

First, type inference produces two possible generic implementations of the call: `Print<Person[]>(Person[] items)` and `Print<Person>(IEnumerable<Person> items)`.

Then overload resolution kicks in and the first one wins, because the second requires an implicit conversion, where the first one does not (see §7.4.2.3 of the C# spec). The same mechanism works for the List variant.

With the added overload, a third possible overload is generated with the List call: `Print<Person>(List<Person> items)`. The argument is the same as with the `Print<List<Person>>(List<Person> items)` but again, section 7.4.3.2 provides the resolution with the language

> Recursively, a constructed type is more specific than another constructed type (with the same number of type arguments) if at least one type argument is more specific and no type argument is less specific than the corresponding type argument in the other.

So the `Print<Person>` overload is more specific than the `Print<List<Person>>` overload and the List version wins over the IEnumerable because it requires no implicit conversion.

Comment: thanks for the mention of implicit casting, it all makes sense now

Answer (score 3):

Because the methods generated from the generics `Print(Person[] item)` and `Print(List<Person> item)` are a better match than `IEnumerable<T>`.

The compiler is generating those methods based on your type arguments, so the generic template `Print<T>(T item)` will get compiled as `Print(Person[] item)` and `Print(List<Person> item)` (well, whatever type represents a `List<Person>` at compilation). Because of that, the method call will be resolved by the compiler as the specific method that accepts the direct type, not the implementation of `Print(IEnumerable<Peson>)`.

Comment: in other words, Print<T> will always be deemed the best match seeing as T can be anything? But if you add a Print<T>(List<T> items) method, that's the method that'll be called for Print(persons.ToList)

Comment: Also, according to this blog post by Eric Lippert, that's not how C# generics work http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/30/generics-are-not-templates.aspx what you described is templates in C++

Comment: The link posted by @theburningmonk is no longer valid; here's an update: https://web.archive.org/web/20151029232904/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/30/generics-are-not-templates.aspx