# Method overload and generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910018/method-overload-resolution-with-regards-to-generics-and-ienumerable), and am trying to do something like:

```
static class ExtentionMethods
{
    static public void MyReset<T>(this T col)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not a collection!");
    }

    static public void MyReset<T, U>(this T col) where T : ICollection<U>
    {
        col.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Cleared!");
    }

    // and maybe more overload for T : IWhatevetInterface<U>
}
```

so that `List<T>` and whoever implement `ICollection<T>` would choose the second method, while `MyClass` (MyClass is just some class that not implementing ICollection, of course) would choose the first, for example:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
list1.MyReset<List<int>, int>(); // "Cleared!"
MyClass x = new MyClass(); 
x.MyReset(); // "Not a collection!"
```

It works fine, but the problem is, how can I avoid writing `<List<int>, int>` for `list1.MyReset<List<int>, int>()`? I'd like to simply writing `list1.MyReset()`.

The goal is to sustain the ability to distinguish `ICollection<T>` and other classes, but also not to explicitly providing the generic parameters.

Responding to comment: I'm planning to add more overloads, so the case is not only `Yes-Collection` and `Not-Collection`.

Comment: Why not just not have the "not a collection" override? Then bad code won't compile, rather than failing at runtime.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I'm planning to add more overloads for example `T : IResetable`, `T: IWhateverYouLike`, etc; So I need to let them match the exact overload.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# does not use generic constraints in its type-inference algorithm.

However, it doesn't look like you actually need type-constraints. You could simplify your code like this, which does work:

```
static public void MyReset(this object col)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a collection!");
}

static public void MyReset<T>(this ICollection<T> col)
{
    col.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Cleared!");
}

static public void MyReset<T>(this IWhateverYouLike<T> col)
{
    col.ClearItIfYouLike();
    Console.WriteLine("Cleared!");
}
```

Comment: sorry, it's my bad that not clarifying there are more than 2 possibilities, please see my edited question

Comment: You can still have more than two possibilities - see my edit. Does this work for you?

Comment: @MarsonMao This answer is really the only viable approach. Your use case doesn't really make sense - Why use templates when you've explicitly said you want to find only `ICollection<T>` types?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I tested your solution and it looks like what I need, thanks! Didnt realize that I can use a non-generic version for the general case!

Comment: @Rob What do you mean? Which part of the template approach is wrong?